# Seeking shapefile for Assam in India?

Tags: shapefile, data, india

I am looking for a shapefile of Assam showing district-wide boundaries. I have searched in the net but I have not been able to locate one for Assam, even though shapefiles for India are available.

Can anyone suggest where I can obtain such a file?

Comment: I suspect that your question might be better researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as pointed out in the Comments it is better suited for the Open Data site.

Comment: This is not a duplicate since Assam is a state, and the linked question is about villages & cities;

Answer (score 3):

You can get various Boundary datasets from here: https://github.com/datameet/maps/

Comment: You will know better than me, but it seems there has been a couple of questions asking for administrative boundaries of India (see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdata%5D+india+%5Bshapefile%5D+is%3Aquestion). Perhaps you could help finding the best Q/A post so far and flag some duplicates of it? Or are these questions not duplicates at all?

Comment: @AndreSilva: Sure, I'll get to it in a couple of days.

Answer (score -1):

There is another web page, which provides you with spatial data all over the world, called [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/). The public available data derive from [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org).

There is a section about spatial data of India including Assam.